# query magento limit + order by rand()

Tags: magento

```
function getIdModelsSliderJuwels(){
 $collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter("attribute_set_id", 27); 
     $collection->addAttributeToSelect('modellijnen'); 
   //  $collection->setRandomOrder();
   //  $collection->getSelect()->limit( 5 ); 
 return $collection; 
}
```

Hi there,

I'd like to know how to set a limit to your query running in Magento because
`$collection->getSelect()->limit( 5 );` doesn't work.

Also how to select randomly, `$collection->setRandomOrder();` also doesn't work.

txs.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? What error do you get?

Comment: Try to view resulting SQL query: echo $collection->getSelect();

Comment: with limit i am getting no error but i am getting back all modellijnen instead of 5

Comment: $collection->setRandomOrder();
 this function he doesnot know

Comment: Just a note for people like me who ended up here looking for how to set an order on collection. I use this: ````->addOrder('banner_order', 'DESC');````

Comment: my trick use

->setPageSize(5)
->setCurPage(rand(1,99))

Answer (score 8):

`setRandomOrder` does not work for collections of products, only for related products. You'll have to add it yourself with this code:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
```

A shortcut for setting both page size and number at the same time is:

```
$collection->setPage($pageNum, $pageSize);
```

Answer (score 4):

As clockworkgeek said, use the `$collection->getSelect()->order(...)` method to randomize the order. To limit it to just `$n` number of items you can also use

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit($n);
```

Comment: Although this triggers a phpcs (MagentoECGM1) warning (Data access method LIMIT detected outside Resource Model) it seems to be the only way of using rand() + limit.

Answer (score 3):

try to use

$collection->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);

Answer (score 1):

Using `ORDER BY RAND()` to return a list of items in a random order will require a full table scan and sort. It can negatively affect performance on large number of rows in the table.

There are several alternative solutions possible of how to optimize this query. Magento provides a native solution for that.

The `orderRand()` method of `Varien_Db_Select` and the database adapter allows to specify a random order and leverage index for `ORDER BY`. Specify a name of some integer indexed column to be used in the `ORDER BY` clause, for example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->orderRand('main_table.entity_id');
```

See `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::orderRand()` for implementation details.