# magento get products from category, order by rand()

Tags: php, collections, magento, random

I have the following:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort('id', 'RAND()')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId));
```

But I need to order by id `RAND()`, how can I do this? (The code shows how I've tried with no luck)

Comment: Don't you mean you want to sort on `RAND()` instead of `id = RAND()`? ASAIK `RAND()` will return a number between 0 and 1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Magento collection do not accept parameters other then one of selected attribute. In this case you should get `Zend_Db_Select` object and add order instruction to it.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSort()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load());
$products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
```

To see what query will be executed you may use this construnction

```
$products->load(true, true); // first parameter show sql query in output, second show sql query in var/log/syslog
```

Comment: You have some great knowledge

Comment: This is a short answer for large output... Thanks a lot.. I have a same requirement and ur solution works a lot..

Answer (score 11):

Refer to this question: [query magento limit + order by rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4144113/336905)  and clockworkgeek's answer:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
```

Comment: Nice. But I think Andrey got it this time.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - absolutely, wasn't trying to take points away from Andrey, just make a subtle point about searching before posting :) Perhaps I should have been less subtle :)

Comment: @JonathanDay I tried this solution but getting following error. Any idea?

Unrecognized method 'setCurPage()'";i:1;s:4108:"#0 ...\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php(225): Zend_Db_Select->__call('setCurPage', Array)

Answer (score 1):

Using `ORDER BY RAND()` to return a list of items in a random order will require a full table scan and sort. It can negatively affect performance on large number of rows in the table.

There are several alternative solutions possible of how to optimize this query. Magento provides a native solution for that.

The `orderRand()` method of `Varien_Db_Select` and the database adapter allows to specify a random order and leverage index for `ORDER BY`.
Specify a name of some integer indexed column to be used in the `ORDER BY` clause, for example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->orderRand('main_table.entity_id');
```

See `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::orderRand()` for implementation details.

Comment: This did work for me: `$collection->getSelect()->orderRand('e.entity_id');` But, at least in my case, this method did not increase performance compared to `->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))`