# Magento custom sort by

Tags: magento

Does anybody know, how may I use a "order by if" statement, in my products list view to sort them by a custom way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all sorts of SQL statements in the order clause - [here is an example with `RAND()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4356019/471559). An [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) could be used in the same way.

If you're working with `getLoadedProductCollection()` in product lists then you should also consider [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285509/471559) for manipulating it. It's not perfect (read the comments too for a discussion) but I find it good enough in most cases.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I was looking mainly for a way to add custom order for the product list. For example to add custom_order order, and then overwrite-extend something so that it checks if we have custom order and then do all the magic.
I think however that i will sort it out using a usort method, after products are loaded