# how to narrow the amount of objects returned and then randomly display these

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I have this php file featured.phtml which loads products from a specific catagory

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
    <?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
        <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

        <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = 6; ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
                <ul class="featured-products-grid">
            <?php endif ?>
                    <li class="hreview-aggregate hproduct item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image') ?>" class="url home-product-image"><img class="photo fn" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" /></a>
                        <h2 class="item fn home-product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h2>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <button id="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span class="ui-button-text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </li>
            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I call this code from my home page on the magento admin as:

{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="14" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}

so basically it looks at category_id=14 and loads all the products into the featured.phtml template

my question:

how do i modify featured.phtml so that it just randomly selects only 5 products and displays them in random order?

thank you for any advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [magento get products from category, order by rand()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356019/magento-get-products-from-category-order-by-rand)

Answer (score 0):

To display simple random product you can use this code.
by using this code you can display random product. but if you want to display random product specific category then you can also add attribute filter of this category.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
    $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
    $collection->addStoreFilter();
    $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();

    //below code to display output

    if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection())):
        echo $_product->getSku(); // just to display sku
    endif;
```

in the above code this will only display product sku. you just need to write code for product name, image, price etc.

hope it will help you.

thanks